# Groovy method cannot access variable in enclosing scope

Tags: groovy

I know that this is what closures are for, but shouldn't the below work as well?:

```
def f = 'foo'
def foo() {
   println(f)
}
foo()
```

It results in:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: f for class: bar
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: f for class: bar
   at bar.foo(bar.groovy:4)
   at bar.run(bar.groovy:7)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a groovy script (as opposed to class), your code is essentially equivalent to:

```
class ScriptName {
  def main(args) {
    new ScriptName().run(args)
  }

  def run(args) {
    def f = 'foo'
    foo()
  }

  def foo() {
    println(f)
  }
}
```

the 'implicit' enclosing class created by groovy for groovy scripts is always present but not visible in your code. The above makes it obvious why the `foo` method does not see the `f` variable.

You have a couple of options

*option 1 - binding*

See the [groovy docs on script bindings](http://groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) for details.

```
// put the variable in the script binding
f = 'foo'
```

(note that we do this without the `def` keyword)

this is shorthand for:

```
binding.setVariable('f', 'foo')
```

where the script binding is visible everywhere for groovy scripts and this makes the variable essentially 'global'.

*option 2 - @Field annotation*

See [groovy docs on the Field annotation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#xform-Field) for details.

```
import groovy.transform.Field
...    
// use the groovy.transform.Field annotation 
@Field f = 'foo'
```

the Field annotation is specifically there to give groovy scripts the ability to add fields to the 'implicit' enclosing class. The generated class would then look something like the following:

```
class ScriptName {
  def f = 'foo'

  def main(args) {
    new ScriptName().run(args)
  }

  def run(args) {
    foo()
  }

  def foo() {
    println(f)
  }
}
```

which also essentially makes the variable accessible 'globally' in the script.

Comment: Your first code block has answered so many questions I had, well done.