# How to evaluate a String which one like a classname.methodname in SoapUI with Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have groovy code as below:

```
def randomInt = RandomUtil.getRandomInt(1,200);
log.info randomInt

def chars = (("1".."9") + ("A".."Z") + ("a".."z")).join()
def randomString = RandomUtil.getRandomString(chars, randomInt)   //works well with this code
log.info  randomString


evaluate("log.info new Date()")

evaluate('RandomUtil.getRandomString(chars, randomInt)')   //got error with this code
```

I want to  evaluate a String which one like a {classname}.{methodname} in SoapUI with Groovy, just like above, but got error here, how to handle this and make it works well as I expect?

I have tried as blew:

```
evaluate('RandomUtil.getRandomString(chars, randomInt)')   //got error with this code
```

Error As below:

> Thu May 23 22:26:30 CST 2019:ERROR:An error occurred [No such property: getRandomString(chars, randomInt) for class: com.hypers.test.apitest.util.RandomUtil], see error log for details

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
log = [info: { println(it) }]

class RandomUtil { 
  static def random = new Random()

  static int getRandomInt(int from, int to) {
    from + random.nextInt(to - from)
  }

  static String getRandomString(alphabet, len) {
      def s = alphabet.size()
      (1..len).collect { alphabet[random.nextInt(s)] }.join()
  }
}

randomInt = RandomUtil.getRandomInt(1, 200)
log.info randomInt

chars = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')

def randomString = RandomUtil.getRandomString(chars, 10)   //works well with this code
log.info  randomString


evaluate("log.info new Date()")

evaluate('RandomUtil.getRandomString(chars, randomInt)')   //got error with this code
```

emulates your code, works, and produces the following output when run:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy
70
DDSQi27PYG
Thu May 23 20:51:58 CEST 2019

~>
```

I made up the RandomUtil class as you did not include the code for it.

I think the reason you are seeing the error you are seeing is that you define your variables `char` and `randomInt` using:

```
def chars = ...
```

and

```
def randomInt = ...
```

this puts the variables in local script scope. Please see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117033/5449431) for an explanation with links to documentation of different ways of putting things in the script global scope and an explanation of how this works.

Essentially your groovy script code is implicitly an instance of the [groovy Script class](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) which in turn has an implicit [Binding instance](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) associated with it. When you write `def x = ...`, your variable is locally scoped, when you write `x = ...` or `binding.x = ...` the variable is defined in the script binding.

The `evaluate` method uses the same binding as the implicit script object. So the reason my example above works is that I omitted the `def` and just typed `chars =` and `randomInt =` which puts the variables in the script binding thus making them available for the code in the `evaluate` expression.

Though I have to say that even with all that, the phrasing `No such property: getRandomString(chars, randomInt)` seems really strange to me...I would have expected `No such method` or `No such property: chars` etc.

Sharing the code for for `RandomUtil` might help here.

Comment: It works well if ```RandomUtil``` class and call code in the same script file,But if I put ```RandomUtil``` in a single file called **RandomUtil.groovy** with package ```package com.test.apitest.util```, then use ```package com.test.apitest.util``` include this class in call script, it will throw exception just like ```No such property: getRandomString(chars, randomInt)```

Comment: **RandomUtil.groovy**

```
package com.test.apitest.util

class RandomUtil {

    static def getRandomInt(def min, def max){
        return Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % max) + min
    }

    static def getRandomString(def customString, def length){
        def randomString = new Random().with {
            (1..length).collect { customString[ nextInt( customString.length() ) ] }.join()
        }

        return randomString
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks I got the solution use full package path include evaluate String: `evaluate("com.test.apitest.util.RandomUtil.getRandomString(chars, randomInt)")`

Comment: aha...ok, that makes sense. Glad you figured it out.