# groovy evaluate string as the function which exists in the same script

Tags: groovy, eval, evaluate

I am trying to evaluate string as code in groovy and it is failing with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` exception even though method exists in the same script. As I understood groovy runs new instance every time it tries to evaluate the code, but is there any way to inject current script into `Eval.me` or `GroovyShell().evaluate()` so that it can find the method and runs it ?
Below is sample code snippet,

```
def justSayHello(){
    return "hello"
}

def my_str = "justSayHello()"
//Eval.me(my_func_str)
new GroovyShell().evaluate(my_func_str)
```

Both `Eval` and `GroovyShell().evaluate()` are throwing below exception

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.justSayHello() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.justSayHello() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
        at string_split.run(string_split.groovy:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
justSayHello = {
  println "hello"
}

def my_str = "justSayHello()"

new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate(my_str)
```

prints out `hello` when run. Here we have changed `justSayHello` from a method (on an implicit class that you can not see but which the groovy compiler generates around your script) to a closure. Further we are not doing `def justSayHello` as that would be defining it as a field on the implicit surrounding class (again which you can't see, but it's there), but rather just defining the variable without any modifiers which puts it in the global binding of the script.

We then send in the binding to the GroovyShell so that it can find the variable.

Result:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
hello
```

A more generic variant is to do something like this:

```
def justSayHello() {
  println "hello"
}

def someOtherMethod() {
  println "hello again"
}

def methods = this.class.declaredMethods.findResults { m -> 
  if (m.name.startsWith('$') || m.name in ['main', 'run']) return null
  [m.name, this.&"${m.name}"]
}.collectEntries { it }

// just for debugging, print the methods
methods.each { k, v -> 
  println "method: $k"
}

def my_str = "justSayHello()"
new GroovyShell(new Binding(methods)).evaluate(my_str)
```

which prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

method: justSayHello
method: someOtherMethod
hello
```

here we find all the declared methods in the implicit class generated by groovy, remove some stuff added by the groovy compiler (namely `main`, `run` and methods starting with a `$`) and then send the resulting map as the binding for the GroovyShell constructor.

I suspect there might be a more elegant way of accomplishing this, so any groovy gurus - feel free to correct me here.

For an explanation of the implicit enclosing class for a groovy script, see for example [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116876/groovy-method-cannot-access-variable-in-enclosing-scope/42117033#42117033).

Comment: thank you @Matias, modifying method as closure does work, but the problem is in my real time scenario method is not defined in the current class, but it is imported from different one. So i don't have any control over it to modify it.

Comment: You could still use the second method and enumerate the declared classes in the class where the method is defined. Should work exactly the same except you replace `this.class.delclaredMethods` with `YourOtherClass.declaredMethods`