# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Cols for class: Script1

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

i have a list like below

```
List<WebElement> Cols = Rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName('td'))
```

I have a method like below

```
 public def queryGenerator(Map inputs)
{
    def firstvalue = 'Cols.get('
    def Secondvalue = ').getText().equals('
    def thirdvalue = ')'
    def ampersand = '&'
    def value = ''

    inputs.each({ def k, def v ->
        int inum = Integer.parseInt(k);
        value = value + firstvalue+(inum-1)+Secondvalue+"\'$v\'"+thirdvalue+ampersand

    })
    return value.substring(0, value.length()-1)

}
```

Now I am going to use Eval from groovy to convert this expression

```
String x = queryGenerator(values) //This will return Cols.get(0).getText().equals("some value")
if(Eval.me(x){}
```

This gives following error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Cols for class: Script1
```

I have checked the groovy documentation most of Eval are using String, Object and Expression. Is there any way so that Eval can recognise the list.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that you are running this from a groovy script (i.e. just a `xxx.groovy` file with code directly in the file without any `class` declarations). If so, please see for example [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116876/groovy-method-cannot-%20access-variable-in-enclosing-scope/42117033#4211703) for information on the scoping of variables in groovy scripts.

Long story short, you this is a groovy script you can try:

```
Cols = Rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName('td'))
```

(i.e. without the initial type declaration) or

```
import groovy.transform.Field
...    
@Field List<WebElement> Cols = Rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName('td'))
```